# Possible DNS Forward Error or DDoS?

Tags: webserver

Our website, http://cybseccoinexplorer.com doesn't seem to be working correctly. DNS and website analysis mentioned that it could be a DNS error. Does anyone have any solutions that could fix this issue? Obviously restarting the server had no luck.

Comment: Website will not load in browser. 'Unable to connect' error. It looks like I can ping the webserver but its not displaying anything